# Is there an easy way to map elements of a list to each other?

Tags: python, list

I am using python. Basically I have a large list with each value having a triple index: `(i, j, t)`:

```
Y_1,2,1
Y_1,3,1
```

and so on.

What I want to do is extract specifically the values: `Y_i,j,t` and `Y_j,i,t`  but I am having some difficulty.

So for example, I would want to be able to extract: `Y_1,2,1` and `Y_2,1,1`. `Y_1,3,4` and `Y_3,1,4`...

To populate my data I use:

```
N = 6
T = 2 * N - 2
list_ijt = []
    
for t in range(1, T + 1):
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        for j in range(1, N + 1):
            # Avoid making Y_i,j=i,t index
            if j == i:
                continue
            element = "Y" + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ',' + str(t)
            list_ijt.append(element)
```

Is there some way to do this for a general case `n`? Would it be easier done with a dictionary? I have tried and tried to come up with some algorithm or equation, like

```
for n in range(len(list_ijt)):
     match_index = 4 * (n + 1) + (n + 1) 
     print(list_ijt[n], list_ijt[match_index])
```

But to no avail, and with no clue how this would be generalized for any `n` (the above example was for `n = 6`).

Example list:

```
print(list_ijt)
['Y1,2,1', 'Y1,3,1', 'Y1,4,1', 'Y1,5,1', 'Y1,6,1', 'Y2,1,1', 'Y2,3,1', 'Y2,4,1', 'Y2,5,1', 'Y2,6,1', 'Y3,1,1', 'Y3,2,1', 'Y3,4,1', 'Y3,5,1', 'Y3,6,1', 'Y4,1,1', 'Y4,2,1', 'Y4,3,1', 'Y4,5,1', 'Y4,6,1', 'Y5,1,1', 'Y5,2,1', 'Y5,3,1', 'Y5,4,1', 'Y5,6,1', 'Y6,1,1', 'Y6,2,1', 'Y6,3,1', 'Y6,4,1', 'Y6,5,1', 'Y1,2,2', 'Y1,3,2', 'Y1,4,2', 'Y1,5,2', 'Y1,6,2', 'Y2,1,2', 'Y2,3,2', 'Y2,4,2', 'Y2,5,2', 'Y2,6,2', 'Y3,1,2', 'Y3,2,2', 'Y3,4,2', 'Y3,5,2', 'Y3,6,2', 'Y4,1,2', 'Y4,2,2', 'Y4,3,2', 'Y4,5,2', 'Y4,6,2', 'Y5,1,2', 'Y5,2,2', 'Y5,3,2', 'Y5,4,2', 'Y5,6,2', 'Y6,1,2', 'Y6,2,2', 'Y6,3,2', 'Y6,4,2', 'Y6,5,2', 'Y1,2,3', 'Y1,3,3', 'Y1,4,3', 'Y1,5,3', 'Y1,6,3', 'Y2,1,3', 'Y2,3,3', 'Y2,4,3', 'Y2,5,3', 'Y2,6,3', 'Y3,1,3', 'Y3,2,3', 'Y3,4,3', 'Y3,5,3', 'Y3,6,3', 'Y4,1,3', 'Y4,2,3', 'Y4,3,3', 'Y4,5,3', 'Y4,6,3', 'Y5,1,3', 'Y5,2,3', 'Y5,3,3', 'Y5,4,3', 'Y5,6,3', 'Y6,1,3', 'Y6,2,3', 'Y6,3,3', 'Y6,4,3', 'Y6,5,3', 'Y1,2,4', 'Y1,3,4', 'Y1,4,4', 'Y1,5,4', 'Y1,6,4', 'Y2,1,4', 'Y2,3,4', 'Y2,4,4', 'Y2,5,4', 'Y2,6,4', 'Y3,1,4', 'Y3,2,4', 'Y3,4,4', 'Y3,5,4', 'Y3,6,4', 'Y4,1,4', 'Y4,2,4', 'Y4,3,4', 'Y4,5,4', 'Y4,6,4', 'Y5,1,4', 'Y5,2,4', 'Y5,3,4', 'Y5,4,4', 'Y5,6,4', 'Y6,1,4', 'Y6,2,4', 'Y6,3,4', 'Y6,4,4', 'Y6,5,4', 'Y1,2,5', 'Y1,3,5', 'Y1,4,5', 'Y1,5,5', 'Y1,6,5', 'Y2,1,5', 'Y2,3,5', 'Y2,4,5', 'Y2,5,5', 'Y2,6,5', 'Y3,1,5', 'Y3,2,5', 'Y3,4,5', 'Y3,5,5', 'Y3,6,5', 'Y4,1,5', 'Y4,2,5', 'Y4,3,5', 'Y4,5,5', 'Y4,6,5', 'Y5,1,5', 'Y5,2,5', 'Y5,3,5', 'Y5,4,5', 'Y5,6,5', 'Y6,1,5', 'Y6,2,5', 'Y6,3,5', 'Y6,4,5', 'Y6,5,5', 'Y1,2,6', 'Y1,3,6', 'Y1,4,6', 'Y1,5,6', 'Y1,6,6', 'Y2,1,6', 'Y2,3,6', 'Y2,4,6', 'Y2,5,6', 'Y2,6,6', 'Y3,1,6', 'Y3,2,6', 'Y3,4,6', 'Y3,5,6', 'Y3,6,6', 'Y4,1,6', 'Y4,2,6', 'Y4,3,6', 'Y4,5,6', 'Y4,6,6', 'Y5,1,6', 'Y5,2,6', 'Y5,3,6', 'Y5,4,6', 'Y5,6,6', 'Y6,1,6', 'Y6,2,6', 'Y6,3,6', 'Y6,4,6', 'Y6,5,6', 'Y1,2,7', 'Y1,3,7', 'Y1,4,7', 'Y1,5,7', 'Y1,6,7', 'Y2,1,7', 'Y2,3,7', 'Y2,4,7', 'Y2,5,7', 'Y2,6,7', 'Y3,1,7', 'Y3,2,7', 'Y3,4,7', 'Y3,5,7', 'Y3,6,7', 'Y4,1,7', 'Y4,2,7', 'Y4,3,7', 'Y4,5,7', 'Y4,6,7', 'Y5,1,7', 'Y5,2,7', 'Y5,3,7', 'Y5,4,7', 'Y5,6,7', 'Y6,1,7', 'Y6,2,7', 'Y6,3,7', 'Y6,4,7', 'Y6,5,7', 'Y1,2,8', 'Y1,3,8', 'Y1,4,8', 'Y1,5,8', 'Y1,6,8', 'Y2,1,8', 'Y2,3,8', 'Y2,4,8', 'Y2,5,8', 'Y2,6,8', 'Y3,1,8', 'Y3,2,8', 'Y3,4,8', 'Y3,5,8', 'Y3,6,8', 'Y4,1,8', 'Y4,2,8', 'Y4,3,8', 'Y4,5,8', 'Y4,6,8', 'Y5,1,8', 'Y5,2,8', 'Y5,3,8', 'Y5,4,8', 'Y5,6,8', 'Y6,1,8', 'Y6,2,8', 'Y6,3,8', 'Y6,4,8', 'Y6,5,8', 'Y1,2,9', 'Y1,3,9', 'Y1,4,9', 'Y1,5,9', 'Y1,6,9', 'Y2,1,9', 'Y2,3,9', 'Y2,4,9', 'Y2,5,9', 'Y2,6,9', 'Y3,1,9', 'Y3,2,9', 'Y3,4,9', 'Y3,5,9', 'Y3,6,9', 'Y4,1,9', 'Y4,2,9', 'Y4,3,9', 'Y4,5,9', 'Y4,6,9', 'Y5,1,9', 'Y5,2,9', 'Y5,3,9', 'Y5,4,9', 'Y5,6,9', 'Y6,1,9', 'Y6,2,9', 'Y6,3,9', 'Y6,4,9', 'Y6,5,9', 'Y1,2,10', 'Y1,3,10', 'Y1,4,10', 'Y1,5,10', 'Y1,6,10', 'Y2,1,10', 'Y2,3,10', 'Y2,4,10', 'Y2,5,10', 'Y2,6,10', 'Y3,1,10', 'Y3,2,10', 'Y3,4,10', 'Y3,5,10', 'Y3,6,10', 'Y4,1,10', 'Y4,2,10', 'Y4,3,10', 'Y4,5,10', 'Y4,6,10', 'Y5,1,10', 'Y5,2,10', 'Y5,3,10', 'Y5,4,10', 'Y5,6,10', 'Y6,1,10', 'Y6,2,10', 'Y6,3,10', 'Y6,4,10', 'Y6,5,10']
```

Tried:

```
string = '\n'.join(list_ijt)
for t in range(T):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            s = get(i, j, t, string)
            if s:
                list_ijt.append(s)
```

Comment: could you give an example of your list? Include the first 10 values

Comment: Yes sure, edited my post.

Comment: Is `t` fixed before running the program?

Comment: Correct. T is dependent on n. Eventually, I want to do this for a number of n, such as n = 6, 10, 14, 18...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is exactly as shown (no missing elements or anything like that), you can analyze the placement of elements pretty easily.

There are a total of `T` blocks of `N * (N - 1)` elements. Each block consists of `N` segments of `N - 1` elements each. Each segment has a constant value of `i`. The first `i - 1` elements are for `j < i` and the remainder for `j > i`.

So for a given choice of `i, j, t`, the index in the list is

```
(t - 1) * N * (N - 1) + (i - 1) * (N - 1) + j - (j > i) - 1
```

The expression `(j > i)` evaluates to a bool, which is an integer that's 0 or 1.

That means that the index for `j, i, t` is given by

```
(t - 1) * N * (N - 1) + (j - 1) * (N - 1) + i - (i > j) - 1
```

So if you have an index in the list, `k`, you can break it down into components and apply the second formula. The components are

```
t = (k // (N * (N - 1))) + 1
i = (k % (N * (N - 1))) // (N - 1) + 1
j = k % (N - 1) + 1
j += (j >= i)
```

So you can compute a match index for any `k` totally deterministically with arithmetic and boolean operations. You don't need loops or dictionaries in this particular case.

You can write your final loop as something like this:

```
for k in range(len(list_ijt)):
    t = (k // (N * (N - 1))) + 1
    i = (k % (N * (N - 1))) // (N - 1) + 1
    j = k % (N - 1) + 1
    j += (j >= i)
    match_index = (t - 1) * N * (N - 1) + (j - 1) * (N - 1) + i - (i > j) - 1
    print(list_ijt[k], '->', list_ijt[match_index])
```

Comment: Hey, this is awesome! I was trying to plug some values to test if it was working, and it wasn't giving me the correct output unless I used ```output - 1```, but perhaps I am not understanding your instruction. What do you mean in terms of 'break it down into the components'? Would you mind providing an example of how I would use this in my example list? I tried plugging in the formula for a loop going over my entire list. Without the -1 it doesn't work, and with the -1 it works for a few values, but not all.

Comment: @mathplzfun. Still fixing, but here's an update

Comment: cool, I was doing something similar. It seems to be bugging up when the value which has already been previously matched comes up again.. An issue I was struggling with too when trying to map them!

Comment: @mathplzfun. I fixed it. There was an error going from `k` to `j`

Comment: Thanks, I see it works for the example I posted. I tried to see if it worked on another example, using n= 6, T = 2*n-2 = 10, but it doesn't work. I am a little confused as to why this would be the case, because the logic for how you split each block should be the exact same, regardless of block size, right?

Comment: @mathplzfun. Correct. did you include the fix `j += (j >= i)`? It works well for me once I do that for `N=6, T=10`.

Comment: Yep, I used the fix, still no luck. I've updated the original post with the code to create the slightly bigger list, and included the list output as well if you wanted to see.

Comment: @mathplzfun. Here's the output: https://ideone.com/ZytUDw. Please show me the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
def get(i, j, t, string):
    def _get(i, j):
        pat = f'Y{i},{j},{t}'
        ind = string.find(pat)
        if ind >=0:
            return string[ind:ind+len(pat)]
    a, b = _get(i, j), _get(j, i)
    if a and b:
        return a, b
    
n = 3
T = 2*n-2
list_ijt = []

string = '\n'.join(your_list)
for t in range(T):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            if s := get(i, j, t, string):
                list_ijt.append(s)

print(list_ijt)
[('Y1,2,1', 'Y2,1,1'), ('Y1,2,2', 'Y2,1,2'), ('Y1,2,3', 'Y2,1,3')]
```

Comment: I am getting an SyntaxError: invalid syntax for the s := part.

Comment: @mathplzfun huh. Thats because you are using python version <=3.7. So you will have to have `s = get(i, j, t, string)` then the next line should be `if s:`

Comment: ah, got it. And where it says 'your_list' is that a placeholder for something? I don't see it defined anywhere else.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure if I edited your code correctly - I updated my original post at the end is that how it should be? Thanks

Comment: @mathplzfun Your list is the list that you have

Comment: Got it. The output is just an empty list for some reason when i print list_ijt.